# How to connect to Openshift Mysql database with PHPstorm?

Tags: mysql, database, phpstorm, openshift

Not succeed after reading stackoverflow and openshift docs. This is the settings and the error message:

http://primere-creatives.rhcloud.com/testing/2014-05-06_11-24-33.jpg

Not sure, have I do port forwarding?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Is there any issues with PhpStorm's own Database support? 2) In any case -- this looks like access misconfiguration on DB side -- double check what users and what hosts are allowed to connect.

Comment: I don't think PhpStorm issue. I hope my setting is wrong but don't know why. I tried many variations but not connected.

Comment: Well ... show us what access permissions/records that user has. Main thing -- what hosts are allowed to connect.

Comment: Can I get access permissions? By ssh putty?

Comment: I'm talking about MySQL permissions here. But yes -- if you can connect to your host via SSH and able to connect to your Db there .. then you may be able to see your permissions 9if you have admin access). If not -- contact your sys admin. **For me** it's DB config issue (on server side) and not IDE.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the MySQL cartridge running on OpenShift you have to first run `rhc port-forward` command. rhc is the command-line client that you can use to work with OpenShift. It is a ruby gem that you can install using `gem install` rhc command. Refer to https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift and https://www.openshift.com/blogs/set-up-local-access-to-openshift-hosted-services-with-port-forwarding

Comment: Thank you, this is succeed: 
http://primere-creatives.rhcloud.com/testing/2014-05-06_16-55-43.jpg

but I used the internal database app of phpstorm, but I like better DB navigator plugin where the "SSH host" dialog is missing. Is it possible to use without this function?

http://primere-creatives.rhcloud.com/testing/2014-05-06_17-03-05.jpg

Comment: As I read, the remote ssh mysql connection is not possible with this plugin within phpstorm. The ssh tunnel plugin works only for deployment but not with databases.